# Variables as address in a mailto link

Tags: php, html, mysql

I would like to use an email value from my database, but when printed it doesn't use the email value or anything after it. Have I missed a ' or " somewhere? It's working other places in the code, but with this link it wont'.

```
echo '<div align="center"><a href="mailto:"' . $row["email"]. '"&subject=Subject&body=Body"><img src="email.png"</a></div>';
```

Outcome link: mailto:

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You closed the href and thats why it ended at mailto:

It should be

```
echo '<div align="center"><a href="mailto:'. $row["email"] .'&subject=Subject&body=Body"><img src="email.png"></a></div>';
```

Comment: Awesome, this added the email. However the subject and body wasn't included.
Link is now: mailto: {mailaddress}

Comment: I noticed more mistakes, try it now

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you very much!

Comment: My pleasure, if your problem is solved, please accept my answer

Comment: @JanneFiH, Your <img tag also isn't closed, so it'll never show the image. Check out my answer for a more ... polished solution, complete w/ spam prevention.

Answer (score 0):

Your quotes are misaligned.

Use this:

```php
// Greatly hinder spammers from ripping the email from your site.
// Converts "hi@hi.com" to "hi&commat;hi&period;com" but still works 100% as good for end-user.
$escapedEmail = htmlentities($row['email'], ENT_HTML5);

echo <<<HTML
    <div align="center"><a href="mailto:{$escapedEmail}&subject=Subject&body=Body"><img src="email.png" /></a></div>
HTML;
```

[Heredocs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) are by far and away the best way to handle this, as you don't have to worry about inter-nested single/double quotes, lots of ".", etc., which are ugly AF and tend to create LOTS of unintended bugs, as your code just bit you with.

Another way to do it is to use `printf()`, but it's not as performant and slightly harder to read:

```php
printf('<div align="center"><a href="mailto:%s&subject=Subject&body=Body"><img src="email.png" /></a></div>', $escapedEmail);
```